# Unable to redirect stderr/stdout to /dev/null in script

Tags: linux, bash, ping

In my script I basically need to wait for the network interface (e.g. en0, eth0, etc) on a linux machine to become fully initialized before my script should continue.  I don't want any output while waiting, and I'm doing the wait like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "\nWaiting for the network to start...\n"

ping_status=$(ping -c 1 server &>/dev/null | egrep -m 2 -e "[0-9]+")
i=0
while [ -z "$status" ]
do
   if [ "$i" -eq 30 ]
   then
      printf "\nServer unresponsive for 30 seconds.  Quitting script\n"
      exit 1
   else
      sleep 1
      i=$((i+1))
      ping_status=$(ping -c 1 server &>/dev/null | egrep -m 2 -e "[0-9]+")
   fi
done
```

The problem is I get the following output until my network is initalized:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The command `ping -c 1 server &>/dev/null | egrep -m 2 -e "[0-9]+"` correctly parses the second line of a successful ping and tells me the bytes, so I know the network isn't up if the return is null.

For some reason, though, I get an actual `egrep` file in my current directory and I still get the above output `connect: Network is unreachable`

- How can I test for a successful ping and discard all output and errors?

Comment: Even the single command is not working for me. 
`status=$(ping -c 1 server &>/dev/null | egrep -m 2 -e "[0-9]+")`

Comment: Nope. empty result. you're redirecting your o/p to /dev/null. then how can you egrep it? `ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 &>/dev/null`

Comment: @Antarus Good point, I guess I don't want any output at all unless the ping is successful.

Comment: besides, for this example, you don't need grep at all... ping sets exit status properly. `while ping -c 1 server &>/dev/null; do ... done` should be sufficient.

Comment: @anishsane no luck using this method either

Comment: @nkon hope you've changed your variable in while. after changing it in the var before

Comment: I just did, and now I'm testing.  I had tried the exact way he typed it above

Comment: & change `server` to `$server` or name of the server like `google.com`

Comment: Since output of `ping` is already stored in `ping_status`, you just want to redirect the `stderr` `ping -c 1 server 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Ok, forget everything else for now. What is the result of `ping server`? Does it _ever_ receive any reply?

Comment: Yes guys, that part is already done (lol)... I'm ok on that part!

Comment: @anishsane yes, because I can run my script successfully once the server is up.  I just need the stupid output to go away.

Comment: @nkon Which bash version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&>` operator is functional in all `bash` starting from version 4. You might want to check this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (see in the examples).

That said, since you only want to redirect error, I suggest you should use:

```
ping -c 1 server 2> /dev/null
```

That's because output of `ping` command is already stored in `ping_status`.

Comment: that was the trick.  Thanks!  Also, it kills me that I read the bash man page and it PREFERS you to use `&>` but doesn't mention anything about version availability!  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

```
ping -c 1 127.0.0.1 | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'
```

Use this result. this will solve the problem

Comment: what is the value for `server` ?

Comment: `server` is just a dns name.

Comment: @nkon try the basic ping with your server. i think something is wrong with the network settings. [take a look](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1696910)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the network settings.  The machine starts up quickly and before the network is fully initialized the ping returns `connect: Network is unreachable` because the info is in the arp table.  I just want to get rid of that message while waiting for it to start up.